# ANDROID SQLITE DATABASE ERROR: INVALID TABLE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i created a function in DatabaseOpenHelper to get all product list of my database but i have error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables

even though i have products table in my database

This is my function : DatabaseOpenHelper

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="SKIP.db";
    private  static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;



    //Constructor

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context){

        super (context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


        //Function get all productlist

    public List<productlist> getProductlist()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        //Make sure the same column name in yor database table
        String[] sqlSelect = {"product_name","product_supp","product_category","product_desc"};

        String tableName = "products"; // make sure this is your table name

        qb.getTables();
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null, null,null,null,null);

        List<productlist> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            do{
                productlist productlist = new productlist();

                productlist.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_id")));
                productlist.setProduct_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_name")));
                productlist.setProduct_supp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_supp")));
                productlist.setProduct_category(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_category")));
                productlist.setProduct_desc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_desc")));

                result.add(productlist);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is the error when i tried to run the application

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.skip, PID: 7443
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.skip/com.example.skip.ProductView}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.findEditTable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1100)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:517)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:392)
        at com.example.skip.DatabaseOpenHelper.getProductlist(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:45)
        at com.example.skip.ProductView.onCreate(ProductView.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
```

This is my Database table

[DATABASE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6fzg.jpg)

Comment: why dont you use ROOM library, it is a great lib by android. Give you compile-time errors, rather than runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the table name on the query builder. Replace

```
qb.getTables();
```

with

```
qb.setTables(tableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make these changes:**

```
Cursor cursor = qb.query(tableName,sqlSelect,null, null,null,null,null);
```